# Inserted a float value into my table but failed to get it back

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, floating-point

I'd like to use floating point values in a SQL Server database. 
I use sqlcmd to create and insert float values into a table then reopen the database using SQL Server Management Studio. I see that my column data type is automatically changed to `real`.

```
Create table tb(input float(10),output float(50) not null);
insert into tb values(1.1234567890,0.0);
```

The value of the first column is then `1.12345684`. I read stuff here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

That real value is displayed with 7 digits only, but my value has 9.
Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

For n value  1-24, the precision is 7 digits.
For precision of 15 digits, try setting the value of n between 25-53.
Try this:
`Create table tb(input float(50),output float(50) not null);
insert into tb values(1.1234567890,0.0);`

Comment: No I don't want to to set it so, I want to set it 10 and 50 only.

Comment: And yes it sais 7 digits but I got 9. Why ?

Comment: are you using select * to view the values?

Comment: I tried it on SQL Server management studio. When I use float(10), the value returned is 1.123457. But when I use float 50, the value returned is 1.123456789

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to don't use `float` type for specifying a length for number of digits, For example:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT CAST(0 as float(10)) As f
UNION ALL SELECT 123456789
UNION ALL SELECT 12345.67890
UNION ALL SELECT 1.234567890
UNION ALL SELECT 1234567890.0
UNION ALL SELECT 0.1234567890
), t1 AS (
SELECT f, CAST(f AS float(1)) f1, CAST(CAST(f AS float(1)) AS DECIMAL(20,10)) as d
FROM t
)
SELECT *, f1-f, d-f, d-f1, CAST(f as varchar(20)), CAST(f1 as varchar(20)), CAST(d as varchar(30))
FROM t1;
```

will result:

```
f            f1           d                     f1-f d-f d-f1 charf        charf1       chard
0            0            0.0000000000          0    0   0    0            0            0.0000000000
1.234568E+08 1.234568E+08 123456792.0000000000  0    0   0    1.23457e+008 1.23457e+008 123456792.0000000000
12345.68     12345.68     12345.6787109375      0    0   0    12345.7      12345.7      12345.6787109375
1.234568     1.234568     1.2345678806          0    0   0    1.23457      1.23457      1.2345678806
1.234568E+09 1.234568E+09 1234567936.0000000000 0    0   0    1.23457e+009 1.23457e+009 1234567936.0000000000
0.1234568    0.1234568    0.1234567910          0    0   0    0.123457     0.123457     0.1234567910
```

In above example you can see some different behaviors of `float` data type and I can say you will ***see*** 7 digits in `f` and `f1` columns!.